# How can I disable a button in AngularJS if there are elements in an array?

Tags: angularjs

I have an object: `model.data`

How can I disable a button if this object has an array of questions and if that array has more than one element?

I did try:

```
data-ng-disabled="model.questions.length > 0"
```

But this does not seem to work at all.

Comment: did you forget `ng-app`?

Comment: I have an ng-app. The other poster than answered is suggesting I need to create a function.

Comment: Your code looks good to me. Can you create a fiddle? You definitely don't need a function for that.

Comment: Could you post what your model looks like? You say it's "model.data" yet then your attempted code references "model.questions" ... is the questions array a direct child of "model" or is it a child of "data" (i.e. should it be "model.data.questions")?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**EDIT**: *Modifying answer in response to posts and comments*

What about:

```
data-ng-disabled="checkQuestions()"
```

And then in your controller:

```
$scope.checkQuestions = function() {
 if (model.questions.length > 1) { // your question said "more than one element"
   return true;
  }
  else {
   return false;
  }
};
```

What it really comes down to is that there are multiple ways to accomplish this task; an expression, a function, a bound variable (as demonstrated by the various responses here). If none of them are working, the problem might lie in your model instead. If you could clear up some inconsistencies (see my comments about asking for the structure of your model... also, are you interested in it disabling if there's anything in the array, or only if there is more than one thing in the array?), it will help figure this out.

Here's a fiddle that shows all three approaches; you'll see that they all work. Compare your controller to the fiddle and see if it comes together.

http://jsfiddle.net/jlmcdonald/P8qjR/3/

Comment: Okay I see now. So I need a function to do the checking.

Comment: Also "has an array of questions" :-) I'm wondering if it would be better for me to make this as a function with a parameter so I could use this in more than one place. Any ideas why AngularJS didn't include something like the ability to do a count rather than having to call a function?

Comment: It's not necessary to call a function; expressions are allowed. I was just offering this more as an alternate way to accomplish the same thing, to see what you report back as its success. If neither the expression nor the function works, the problem likely lies in your model (see my comment on your post about having you show us what your model looks like).

Comment: Please include in the answer that you need a function to make this happen. You can't just do it with an expression. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

You definitely can use an expression instead of a function. But you may check if the array is `undefined`.

```
<button ng-disabled="model.questions != undefined && model.questions.length > 0"></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get @zsong answer to work and I didn't want to create a function just to return an array length, so I got it working by creating another scope variable which returned the array.length.

```
$scope.modelQuestionsLength = $scope.model.questions.length;
```

I could then do

```
<button ng-disabled="modelQuestionsLength > 0"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model then set its default value to false. Then change its value to true, if your array length is not empty. Followed with binding the model to the button's ng-disabled attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the undefined way to work, so if anyone else is having trouble, this worked for me:

```
<input ng-disabled="fieldsPermittedForEdit.indexOf('postDate') < 0">
```

In this example, I am disabling the field unless `postDate` exists in the `fieldsPermittedForEdit` array.